# How to return a function value from pcall() in lua

Tags: lua

My code (psuedo)

```
function foo(cmd)
    return load(cmd) --Note that this could cause an error, should 'cmd' be an invalid command
end

function moo()
    return "moo"
end

function yoo(something)
    something.do()
end

cmd = io.read() --Note that a syntax error will call an error in load. Therefore, I use pcall()
local result, error = pcall(cmd)
print(result)
```

This code looks okay, and works, but my problem is if I type in `moo()` then `result` will only show whether or not the command was executed without an error (If the command calls an error, `error` will have its value).

On another note, if I want to call `yoo()`, I won't get a return value from it, so I want `pcall()`'s `true` / `false` (or any alternate means other than `pcall()`)

Is there an alternate way to call `moo()`, get a return value, and also be able to catch any errors?

NOTE: I couldn't find any `try catch` equivalent other then `pcall` / `xpcall`.

Comment: The global namespace may help you here...How about: local status, result = pcall(_G[cmd]) ? The "result" can be either the function result or any  error that the function throws using the function error({anything = 123}).

Comment: To get a returned value, you should type `return moo()` instead of `moo()`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff As I said, this is psuedo code. The biggest problem (which I am adding to the answer's edit) is that I may or may not be wanting a return value. A variety of functions are being called, some of which have no return value

Comment: @GreenHawk1220 - Even for a function which doesn't return a value, it is absolutely correct in Lua to call it as `return yoo()`.  So, always use `return` to solve your problem

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff I get what you are saying, and will remember that in the future, but it still doesn't solve my problem...

Answer (score 0):

A bit outdated but still without proper answer...

What you are looking for is a combination of both `load()` and `pcall()`

1. Use `load()`to compile the entered string `cmd` into something that can be executed (function).
2. Use `pcall()` to execute the function returned by `load()`
3. Both functions can return error messages. Get syntax error description from `load()` and runtime error description from `pcall()`

   ```
   function moo()
     return "moo"
   end

   function yoo(something)
       something.do_something()
   end

   cmd = io.read()

   -- we got some command in the form of a string
   -- to be able to execute it, we have to compile (load) it first
   local cmd_fn, err = load("return "..cmd);
   if not cmd_fn then
       -- there was a syntax error
       print("Syntax error: "..err);
   else
       -- we have now compiled cmd in the form of function cmd_fn(), so we can try to execute it
       local ok, result_or_error = pcall(cmd_fn)
       if ok then
           -- the code was executed successfully, print the returned value
           print("Result: "..tostring(result_or_error));
       else
           -- runtime error, print error description
           print("Run error: "..result_or_error)
       end
   end
   ```

Comment: This might work on one condition. If I ask lua to return a value from a void function, what will happen?